# using tesserract ocr in android I get WindowLeaked and UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, ocr

I am trying to implement OCR in android.
I am trying to execute a sample I found 
but this is the errors I am getting

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeInitOem
at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.nativeInitOem(Native Method)
at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.init(TessBaseAPI.java:240)
at                      edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.OcrInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(OcrInitAsyncTask.java:302)
at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.OcrInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(OcrInitAsyncTask.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 4 more
Activity edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f0e6b0 that was originally added here

android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity has leaked window         com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f0e6b0 that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.initOcrEngine(CaptureActivity.java:698)
at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:371)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I believe you haven't added the OCR library correctly. It can't find the library, hence the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. If it's an C/C++ library, you have to do `ndk-build` in the project folder.